# TortoiseSVN user access issue - Request for login credentials looping in browser and desktop app

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have an account trying to access a specific file path in our repo but it keeps prompting for login details, no error message appears just the enter credentials window.

This appears on our web interface as well as the tortoiseSVN app on desktop.

I've checked the authz file and they do have access. We've had issues before with incorrectly spelled usernames causing permission issues for the whole repository. I didn't see anything wrong but I could still be missing one.

No other users are experiencing issues accessing that file path either, the account only has access to that file path.

If anyone has any ideas, maybe small things I might have missed or common mistakes, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify the versions of TortoiseSVN and your Subversion server, events logged to the server's log, the protocol and authentication method.

Comment: SVN version 1.10.0
Apache/2.4.41
I don't know what version of TortoiseSVN the user is using, but mine's 1.14.1, Build 29085 - 64 Bit
as for protocol and authentication method, I'm not sure how to answer those, could you point me in the direction of where I can find these?

Comment: you could find the authentication method either by examining the server's httpd.conf / svnserve.conf files or by examining the servers admin console (if it has one).

Comment: if you use VisualSVN Server, the logs can be found in Windows Event Viewer in the log named "VisualSVN Server". If you use another server distribution, check httpd.conf or svnserve.conf files for location of your logs.

Comment: @bahrep I appreciate your follow up comments. Fortunately (unfortunately?) the user was able to log in, we're not really sure what happened but it's all working now